# Converting view from ERB to HAML to print HTML class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, erb

I have this ERB:

```
<li class="<%= pill_class_for(:home, :index) %>"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
```

`pill_class_for` is a is a helper function that returns a string representing a HTML class.  How can I change this to HAML?

I tried this but it's stupid and doesn't work:

```
%li.= pill_class_for(:home, :index)<a href="/">Home</a>
```

You can see what I'm trying to do above but it results in a `SyntaxError` (`Illegal element: classes and ids must have values.`).

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following

```
%li{:class => pill_class_for(:home, :index)}
  %a{:href => "/"} Home
```